# How to configure IIS to host a website (like example.com) and an application (example.com/test) which each one of them has a web.config file?

Tags: .net, iis, web-config

How to configure IIS to host a website (like example.com) and an application (example.com/test) which each one of them has a web.config file and I get the following error when I try to access the application which I created inside the website: cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' in web.config file. Both the website and the application are developed in .Net. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have something defined in the child web.config that has already been defined within the parent web.config.  For me to be more specific and revise this answer, I would need to see the parent and child web.config files.

Comment: yes you are right, a part of the web.config file is the same for the child and the parent, but  I need this configuration in the child too or is it enough to just have this lines in the parent web.config and they will be applied in the child too?

Comment: It should be enough to have it in the parent.  The effects of parent/child web.configs are cumulative.  That is, the parent inherits from the child.

See [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx) for more info

Comment: I fixed the issue as you said, putting what was the same only in the parent web.config. But I'm having another issue now, the website shows me the error javascript is disabled, please enable to view this content, it doesn't have to do with the browser. In the browser console I see the error that my javascripts are not defined, as far as I searched I can say that this is caused because IIS is looking for the scripts in the root directory where the localhost runs and not in the subdirectory where the web app is. I saw that If I put smth like ~/ it would work, but can I do this using URL rewrite?

Comment: Some feedback: (1) If you feel that I answered you question then please mark the answer as the correct answer. (2) I recommend that you place your new problem in a new SO post as (this prevents run-on comment threads).  

However, before you do that, (a) what are the steps to repeat the error, and (b) the code that you are using (ASP? pure HTML? something else?) and (c) what is the smallest case that you can provide in order to someone to understand the problem and suggest an answer.  Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)